# How can I force delayed_job to use a specific db connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a Rails 3 applications that uses different databases depending on the subdomain. I do this by using "establish_connection" in the ApplicationController.

Now I'm trying to use delayed_job gem to do some background processing, however it uses the database connection that it's active in that moment. It's connecting to the subdomain database.

I'd like to force it to use the "common" database. I've done this for some models calling "establish_connection" in the model like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["#{Rails.env}"]
  ...
end
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: We're running into the exact same issue. Would love a response. BTW, JAG, what are you using to do subdomain-based multitenancy? We're working on a gem and would love some input.

Comment: I've rolled my own as I didn't find anything suitable for my needs. Basically I have a 'setup_subdomain' before_filter which switches to the appropriate DB. I would love to check out your gem, any link?

Comment: Possibly modify the delayed_job gem, if it on Github is the only way and include it using :git=> in your gemfile.

Comment: @JAG, we're still working on it, but you can play around with it on github at http://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment. If you're using Postgres it's pretty reliable, SQLite and MySQL work in theory but we haven't really tested them.

Answer (score 18):

Here is what you need to know. When you include the DelayedJob gem in your app you create a migration for it to create the table where the jobs are stored, but you don't create a model. This is because DelayedJob already has a model included in the gem (i.e. `Delayed::Job`). What you need to do is patch this model slightly, just like you did with your own models. You can do this in an initializer.

You may already have an initializer to configure DelayedJob, if so you can do this in there, if not you need to create one. So, create your initializer (in `config/initializers`) if you don't have one, we'll call it `delayed_job_config.rb`, now add the following to it:

```
Delayed::Job.class_eval do
  establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["#{Rails.env}"]
end
```

We've done to the DelayedJob model the same thing you did to your own models. Now DelayedJob will use that connection to put jobs in the DB.

Comment: Been a while since you posted this but I can't get this working at all? I've done exactly as you've said above, restarted my web server, but DJ still sticks the jobs in the database of my current environment, rather than what I've specified in my config file. No idea how to debug it either.

Comment: The answer is a little unclear I guess, but this line `establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["#{Rails.env}"]` will make your delayed job just follow your current environment, as it would do by default, you need to replace `Rails.env` with whatever database connection you actually want e.g. `establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["common"]`

Comment: Great explanation. You should write tutorials! :)