# Force Delayed Job to use a separate DB connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

My app is set up in such a way that we use a different database connection per subdomain, using different environments. Delayed Job does what you'd expect (I guess) and uses the current environment of that request (and thus DB connection) when inserting the job to it's delayed_jobs table.

Problem is that DJ can't process jobs from all these different tables, so I'm trying to force DJ to use just one database, especially set up for it. I have tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479039/how-can-i-force-delayed-job-to-use-a-specific-db-connection) but it just won't work and I've no idea what to try next.

Any pointers/suggestions would be VERY much appreciated, really at my wits end with this.

Attempted code:

```
Delayed::Job.class_eval do
  establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["delayed_job"]
end
```

Connection to the DB is done in a `before_filter` in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Can you describe your environment more? i.e. how many web servers, delayed job servers, how you are assigning DB's in each, and show the establish_connection code.

Comment: 1 web server, 1 app, 1 delayed job server. Connection to the DB is done in a before_filter in the application controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force delayed\_job to use a specific db connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479039/how-can-i-force-delayed-job-to-use-a-specific-db-connection)

Answer (score 1):

The code in ApplicationController to establish the connection per the domain will happen only in your application server on each request.

Add a :domain attribute to your Job class and set it when you queue the job. In Job#perform, establish your DB connection.

Comment: You've answered something which wasn't exactly what I was asking, but still deserves a vote up. I made a schoolboy error and the code in my question does in fact work. I've requested the question is closed.